# Extracting SwiftUI Stepper to subview changes its range?

Tags: swiftui

With `SwiftUI` I added a `Stepper` and use its infinite range to increment/decrement a value in my viewmodel. Extracting the Stepper to the subview `StepperView` it now has a range of 5. I can't find how they differ from another and can't find a way to fix the StepperView to be infinite as the initializer **either** sets a range (which I could set to near-infinite values) **or** allows defining `onIncrement`/`onDecrement`

Full example code below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
              Stepper {
              } onIncrement: {
                viewModel.increment()
              } onDecrement: {
                viewModel.decrement()
              }
              StepperView(viewModel: viewModel)
            }
        }
      }
    }
}

struct StepperView: View {
  var viewModel: ContentView.ViewModel
  var body: some View {

    Stepper {
    } onIncrement: {
      viewModel.increment()
    } onDecrement: {
      viewModel.decrement()
    }
  }
}

extension ContentView {
  @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value = 10

    func increment() {
      value += 1
    }

    func decrement() {
      value -= 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are injecting `ObservableObject` into a `View` like you do for `StepperView` you have to mark it as `@ObservedObject` for it to work correctly:

```
struct StepperView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentView.ViewModel

    // etc.

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. The stepper now works the same as the directly created stepper. But I don't understand how that changes the steppers range..